# How to get attributes value while parsing xml with XML::DOM parser in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, dom

How can I get actual attribute value instead of `XML::DOM::NamedNodeMap=HASH(0xa3246d4)` while using getAttribute function from XML::DOM parser

Code

```
 my $parent = $doc->getElementsByTagName ("ParentTag")->item(0);
         my @parent = $childnodes->getChildNodes();
         {
           foreach  my $parent(@parent) 
            {
             if ($parent->getNodeType == ELEMENT_NODE)
               {
                 print $parent->getNodeName;
                 print $parent->getAttributes;
               }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of getAttributes looks to be an [`XML::DOM::NamedNodeMap`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/NamedNodeMap.pod) object, so you can use that object to get attribute values by name, e.g.

```
my $nodemap = $parent->getAttributes;
my $node = $nodemap->getNamedItem('foo');
```

`$node`, in turn will be an [`XML::DOM::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM/Node.pod) object, which will have its own methods and will have its own documentation.

There are a lot of classes and reading through all their [docs](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm#XML::DOM_Classes) will help. If it seems like too much, you might be able to make use of [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egrantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm), which is usually good enough until its no longer good enough :-)

Comment: Thank you jsoverson for your response. I was thinking of XML::Simple but somehow decided on XML::DOM as I have used DOM Parser Earlier.

Comment: XML::DOM is not really maintained these days. Did you try XML::LibXML? It's probably a better option these days if you want to use the DOM.

Comment: I have not tried XML::LibXML but I would surely try it but recently it has been decided to use SAX parser and I guess for SAX Parsing in Perl we have XML::SAX::Intro and XML::Parser::PerlSAX